# To count business days having holiday list in hiveql

Tags: mysql, sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am having two tables one is `biz_date` and `holiday`.

```
create table biz_date (t_date string,start_date string,biz_day int)
create table holiday (h_date string)
```

Now i want to count number of h_date that comes between t_date and start_date for each row in biz_date table and then subtract it from biz_day . biz_day is the business day for that day of month,and start_date is the starting date of t_date's month.eg
biz_date
1990-02-06 1990-02-01 4

I tried this hiveql query

```
select b.t_date,b.biz_day,b.biz_date-cnt,h.h_date,
if(b.start_date>=h_date && b.t_date> h.h_date) then count(h_date)as cnt
from biz_date b,holiday h;
```

Comment: Why are your dates strings? I cannot stress this enough: **dates are not strings so do not store them as strings. Dates are... *dates*, so store them using an appropriate data type e.g. `datetime`**

Comment: You tried your query and ... ?  What is your exact question?

Comment: actually m writing hiveql,date datatype is not supported in hive,so i had to choose string.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the number of holidays between h_date and start_date for each record in the t_date biz_date table.  I strongly recommend storing your dates as dates not strings.  Otherwise if the dates are not formatted correctly, or are not in YEAR/MONTH/DAY order, this may not work correctly.

```
SELECT bd.*,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM holiday WHERE h_date BETWEEN bd.t_date AND bd.start_date) as holiday_count

FROM   biz_date as bd
```